# Postgresql how to select a value from multiple jsons inside a array on a jsonB column

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have this table

```
create table <table_name>(attr jsonb)
```

And this is the data inside

```
{
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "foo",
      "name": "test_01",
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": "bar",
      "name": "test_02",
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want is to select both names, what I have accomplished so far is this

```
select attr -> 'rules' -> 0 -> 'name' from <table_name>;
```

which returns test_01

```
select attr -> 'rules' -> 1 -> 'name' from <table_name>;
```

which returns test_02

I want to return something like this:

```
test_01,test_02
```

or if it's possible to return them in multiple lines, that would be even better

This is a sample data to show my problem, for reasons beyond my control, it's not possible to store each rule on a distinct line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_length` together with `generate_series` to get each name. Then use `string_agg` to aggregate list of names. Without plpgsql and with a single statement. (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=899a26077a3b526d9d2edfe038ed27d0))

```
with jl(counter) as ( select jsonb_array_length(attr->'rules') from table_name ) 
   select string_agg(name,' ') "Rule Names" 
     from (select attr->'rules'-> n ->> 'name' name
             from table_name 
             cross join ( select generate_series(0,counter-1) from jl ) gs(n) 
          ) rn;
```

Answer (score 0):

if anyone else get stuck on a situation like this, this is the solution the I found

```
create or replace function func_get_name() RETURNS text
language 'plpgsql'
AS $$
declare 
    len character varying(255);
    names character varying(255);
    res character varying(255);
   
begin 
    select jsonb_array_length(attr->'rules') into len from <table_name>;
    res := '';

    for counter in 0..len loop
        
        select attr->'rules'-> counter ->> 'name'
        into names
        from <table_name>;
    
        if names is not null then
        res := res || ' ' || names;
        end if;
    
    end loop;
    return res;
end;
$$

select func_get_name();
```

it's a solution: yes, it's a good solution: I have no ideia

Comment: All working solutions are good, they just might not be optimal.